# Background image of ListView/GridView element get disappear while scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gridview

On some devices-(Samsung tab(version 3.0),Nexus (version 4.1) and Htc one v (version 4.0)) but not all(Like galaxy (version 2.2),Htc WildFire (Version 2.3.3)),the background image of ListView/GridView disappears while scrolling

**1-When no movement ,it look like this** (Please see outer rounded white frame )

[image]

**2-But while scrolling the outer frame get disappears for few milliseconds(shows flickering)**

[image]

My inflated xml layout(converView) look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/movieLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:background="@drawable/frame"
        android:padding="4dp" >

        <!-- android:background="@drawable/movie_image_frame_shape" -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/movieImg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/artwork_moviehomepage" >
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/movieName"
        style="@style/textviewStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/movieLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:lines="2"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/NORMAL_TEXT_SIZE"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/movieReleaseDate"
        style="@style/textviewStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/movieName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_yellow"
        android:textSize="@dimen/NORMAL_TEXT_SIZE"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/prebook_ribon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/prebook_ribbon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the grid view is this

```
  <GridView
        android:id="@+id/movieImgGridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="@color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/movie_img_horizontal_spacing"
        android:listSelector="@color/transparent"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Could you post your solution?

Comment: @Rahul Bhardwaj wht is the soln?

Comment: I voted this down because the poster solved the problem but did not post the solution.